# how to create a registration form with different user role?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, user-roles, user-registration

Aside from creating username and password.

I added this form for selecting user privilege.

-Administrator
-Event Facilitator
-Attendance Checker

Each has a different role.

How can i insert PHP code to assign privileges to each role of the user to access certain data and table.

```
<div class="login-fields">
    <p>Select user privilege:</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User Privilege:</label>
        <select id="priv" name="user_pr" maxlength="50" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'>
            <option hidden disabled selected>Select User Role</option>
            <optgroup label="User Privilege">
                <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
                <option value="facilitator">Facilitator</option>
                <option value="checker">Checker</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

another things is, I inserted another field if the Facilitator option has been selected. This field will let the administrator assign the Facilitator to a certain event to be managed by providing him/her an EventID from the database.

```
<div class="login-fields" id="eventid" style='display:none'>
  <p>Assign an Event:</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Event ID">
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript for accessing the EventID field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkvalue(val)  {
      if(val==="facilitator")
        document.getElementById('eventid').style.display='block';
      else
        document.getElementById('eventid').style.display='none';
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___